# How to write code which will only repeat a random number once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is what I have so far:

```
import random
for x in range(10):
    tickets = [random.sample(range(0,59), 6)]
    print (tickets)
```

But I need to make it so that all the numbers generated are different except for two numbers which are the same.

So that's my problem and would appreciate help before Friday! This is the question I was asked for reference:  "My new year's resolution is to win the lottery. To do this I will buy 10 tickets each week. I shall choose 6 numbers at random for each ticket. The numbers range from 1 to 59. All the numbers can only be used once except for one which will need to be duplicated. Write a program in python to simulate this."

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Could you not use `random.shuffle(range(60))` and chunk that list into 10 sublists? The "except for two numbers which are the same" is not clear to me.

Comment: What exactly does the desired output look like? Currently you just `print` the result. Can numbers be repeated across iterations of `tickets`?

Comment: right now i comes up with: [[50, 48, 12, 0, 4, 39]]
[[17, 54, 53, 42, 5, 58]]
[[7, 22, 38, 44, 48, 39]]
[[39, 7, 22, 49, 4, 44]]
[[31, 5, 29, 14, 18, 13]]
[[50, 47, 11, 12, 6, 5]]
[[43, 32, 31, 34, 0, 10]]
[[49, 45, 56, 55, 58, 1]]
[[53, 2, 21, 34, 9, 44]]
[[49, 14, 0, 11, 57, 13]] but my problem is that some numbers are repeated , like 49 and 50 but my assignment is that only one number is allowed to have a duplicate, sorry for not making that clear and hope now I did a better job!

Comment: But a duplicate _where_? Within a single sublist? Is the duplicate _required_?

Comment: it has to be in one of the 10 tickets and the duplicate in a different ticket. this is the question: "My new year's resolution is to win the lottery.

To do this I will buy 10 tickets each week.

I shall choose 6 numbers at random for each ticket.

The numbers range from 1 to 59.

All the numbers can only be used once except for one which

will need to be duplicated.

Write a program in python to simulate this."

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid repeated numbers by keeping track of those that have been used and disallowing them in later samples:

```
import random

def non_repeating_random_sample(population, k, seen):
    while True:
        sample = random.sample(population, k)
        if not any(number in seen for number in sample):
            seen.union(sample)
            return sample

seen = set()
for _ in range(10):
    tickets = [non_repeating_random_sample(range(0, 59), 6, seen)]
    print(tickets)
```

When doing something like this, it may be important to understand that the samples returned—except for the first one—aren't really random because of the additional restraint.

Regardless, it would be simpler and faster to just shuffle the entire population, and then extract groups of of the desired size from it:

```
import random

number_of_samples = 10
number_per_sample = 6

samples = list(range(number_of_samples*number_per_sample))
random.shuffle(samples)

generator = zip(*[iter(samples)]*number_per_sample)
for _ in range(number_of_samples):
    print(list(next(generator)))
```